# How to hide a post from 'Recent Posts' widget?

Tags: posts, recent-posts

I'm trying to hide a post from the 'Recent Posts' widget in the sidebar. I know I can do this with the 'Special Recent Posts' plugin, but that plugin really uses up a lot of resources.

I've got the 'WP Hide Post' plugin, but that doesn't hide a post from the recent posts widget.

So how do I go about doing this?

I don't know any coding, so if you do give me any code, you'd have to tell me where to place it.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can exclude posts from the *recent posts widget* via the `widget_posts_args` filter:

```
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'exclude_posts_wpse_103570');

function exclude_posts_wpse_103570( $args ){
    // post ID's to exclude:
    $args['post__not_in'] = array( 123, 234, 345 );
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Pasted the above into my custom_functions.php file, and it Worked like magic! Thank you birgire.